# Filtering on Celltable

Tags: gwt-2.5

I have a requirement where i need to have filter textbox for each celltable, whenever i enter some text on that, only matching data should displayed in the Celltable. I want the similar feature which smartgwt provides in the following url: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_adaptive_filter_featured_category

I can't go for smartgwt. Most of the people asked about the similar questions. I didn't see any complete example anywhere. I am new to GWT. Can you please provide steps or links or samples to implement the filtering on celltable.

Thanks, Saritha

Answer (score 0):

I use Smartgwt so don't know the client side filtering features of the CellTable widget.
But you can still implement the filtering server side (with very large set of data the time spend server side could be smaller..)
So without knowing the CellTable, I will pick up the changed event on the filter textbox I will send a new Rpc request with the filter criteria.